# ajax does not response

Tags: php, ajax

I try to take a response but I could not. I can't describe it why it does not work or what it is wrong.

```
var virmanYap = function(){
   $("#loading").show();
   $("#tblVirman").hide();
   alert('Virman');
   var data = $("#virman_filtre").serialize();
   $.post("php/virman_yap.php", data).success(function(r){
        alert(r);
   });
}
```

my php code:

```
foreach ($_POST['virman'] as $evrakNo => $detay) {
    print_r($_detay);
}
echo "asd";
```

Comment: There is no `.success()` function.  Try `.done()` instead.

Comment: Just a few minutes ago It works when I change php file it start to failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $.ajax instead of $.post:

```
var virmanYap = function () {
    $("#loading").show();
    $("#tblVirman").hide();
    alert('Virman');
    var data = $("#virman_filtre").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/virman_yap.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `$.post` documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

As you can see, success callback is one of the parameters, you don't need to chain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("php/virman_yap.php", data, function(r){
        alert(r);
});
```

Do something like this. Just remove the chained success function and you should be good.